# Problema ao executar test controller no rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testes, testes-de-unidade

Boa tarde,

Gerei um scaffold de uma classe minha, exemplo User. Ao executar os teste me deparei com a seguinte falha:

```
Minitest::Assertion: "User.count" didn't change by 1.
 Expected: 3
  Actual: 2
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

o código referente a esse erro é:

```
test "should create user" do
  assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, user: { name: 'teste', password: 'secret', password_confirmation: 'secret' }
  end
  assert_redirected_to user_path(assigns(:user))
end
```

Esse é o código gerado pelo scaffold, só alterei a referencia do name.

Pelo que pude entender é que o create não está sendo executado.
Já coloquei um brakpoint no create do controller mas não para lá.

Será que estou fazendo algo errado?

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: *"Só alterei a referência do name"* Como assim? Não entendi o que você alterou. Talvez isso tenha causado o problema. Poste também o código do modelo e controlador de User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema,

Eu tinha esquecido de colocar o usuário na sessão

Comment: Já cometi este erro também =) Apenas marque sua resposta como a correta para ajudar quem pesquisar pela pergunta.